# NamedQuery returning entities with null fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

defined entity with namedquery as `SELECT mdl FROM tbl_slots mdl where  mdl.test_date between :dt and :dt order by mdl.test_time asc`

if used `*` instead of `mdl` in query, JPA gives error `unexpected token: *`

if mentioned the column names in select statement it returns entities with respective fields populated with expected values

> [{
> "srNo": 1,
> "testDate": "2021-Dec-30",
> "testTime": "09:00-10:00",
> },{
> "srNo": 2,
> "testDate": "2021-Dec-30",
> "testTime": "11:00-12:00",
> }]

***how to get same result without mentioning column names in select statement as if used `*`?***

***what's valid JPQL or HQL for `select * from table` query?***

**Entity class**

```
@Table(name = "tbl_slots")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="slots",query = "SELECT mdl FROM tbl_slots mdl where  mdl.test_date between :dt and :dt order by mdl.test_time asc")
})
public class TblSlots implements Serializable {
    private Long srNo;
    private Date testDt;
    private String testTime;
        
    public TblSlots() {}
    public TblSlots(Long srNo, Date testDt, String testTime) {
        this.srNo = srNo;
        this.testDt = testDt;
        this.testTime = testTime;
    }
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "sr_no", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 16, scale = 0)
    public Long getSrNo() {
        return this.srNo;
    }

    public void setSrNo(Long srNo) {
        this.srNo = srNo;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "test_date", nullable = false, length = 13)
    public Date getTestDt() {
        return this.testDt;
    }

    public void setTestDt(Date testDt) {
        this.testDt = testDt;
    }

    @Column(name = "test_time", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getTestTime() {
        return this.testTime;
    }

    public void setTestTime(String testTime) {
        this.testTime = testTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL understand java entities and not columns.

> how to get same result without mentioning column names in select
> statement as if used *?
>
> **what's valid JPQL or HQL for select * from table query?**

So a valid JQPL SELECT query can even not have the `SELECT` clause.

The following would be a valid JPQL query to return the complete entities from that table

```
FROM tbl_slots mdl where  mdl.test_date between :dt and :dt order by mdl.test_time asc
```

So your annotation could be written as

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="slots",query = "FROM tbl_slots mdl where  mdl.test_date between :dt and :dt order by mdl.test_time asc")
})
```

Comment: in DAO layer , it was returning `query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(TabScheduleSlots.class)).list()` due to which it wasnt working even for table reference in select statement , removing setResultTransformer method call and just keeping list() call it started showing  expected result
i know since v5.2 its deprecated, it is mostly used in case of custom resultset ouput but **how can we make it work with setResultTransformer() method?**

Comment: @shreeramaute `query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(TblSlots.class))` would be the correct one

Comment: sorry that was typo thank you for correcting
you solution works for normal query.list() call, but for query.setResultTransformer() approach doesn't work, it produces null pointer exception for query you provided

Comment: @shreeramaute what is exactly the null pointer error?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.initialize(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:98)
org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:68)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:85)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultList(QueryLoader.java:508)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list

Comment: @shreeramaute, this query is supposed to return `List<TblSlots>` correct? If that is the case then you don't need any Transformer to be applied. So you can directly invoke .`list()`. If you wish to transform the response from `List<TblSlots>` to something different then you have to implement and provide the relevant transformer. That is the issue that you face I think

Answer (score 0):

You can not use '*', Because Hibernate is turning objects.
If you want to use *, Use `@NamedNativeQuery` not @NamedQuery

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="slots",query = "SELECT mdl FROM Member mdl ")
})
// Use this
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name="slots_native",query = "SELECT * FROM Member mdl ",resultClass = MemberEntity.class)
})
```

Reference [@NamedNativeQuery](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-named-query)

Comment: using ORM to make app database independent, so @carmel dont want to go for native query